# AWS Command Line Interface failed after intalling through MSI

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services, windows-installer

After installing AWS CLI using the following link:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/awscli-install-windows.html

And adding AWSCLI (`C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSCLI`) path to the environmental variable PATH, when running the command `aws` it throws the error:

> The application has failed to start because it's side-by-side configuration is incorrect. Please see the application event log or use the command-line sxstrace.exe tool for more detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you install Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 redistributable package:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=15336

and restart the Command Line, it solves the problem.

Comment: That is the kind of feedback you should send back to the vendor I think.